# SQL statement to find The number of customers who sign up and did not order

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, right-join

I am looking for a query than can list the customers:

1. customers who sign up but not orders.
2. customers who order more than 1 time.

I have 2 Table Users and Orders:

- Users table:
  `user_id, created_at`
- Orders table:
  `orders_id, order_no, customer_id, created_at.`

**customer_id in the orders table is user_id**

I wrote this SQL query statement but I couldn't find a result

```sql
SELECT Users.user_id,
FROM Users
JOIN Orders
ON customer.id=Orders.customer_id
```

Could someone please help me out with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT U.user_id 
FROM Users AS U
LEFT JOIN Orders AS O ON U.customer.id=O.customer_id
WHERE O.customer_id IS NULL
```

It is for "customers who sign up but not orders."

```
SELECT U.user_id 
FROM Users AS U
JOIN Orders AS O ON U.customer.id=O.customer_id
GROUP BY U.user_id 
HAVING COUNT(O.orders_id) >1
```

It is for "customers who order more than 1 time"

Comment: What about this SQL statement  SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM users
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT *
   FROM  orders
   WHERE users.id = orders.customer_id)

Comment: for me looks OK